# NRefactory doesn't see comma

Tags: c#, code-analysis, nrefactory

NRefactory doesn't see comma symbol as code node in anonymous type fields description. Code is valid and compile. But he see it in function parameters.
Bug? Or needed special parsing parameters?

[image: screenshot of NDRefactory Demo]

[image]

They write that it is fixed: 
https://github.com/icsharpcode/NRefactory/issues/32
But still not fixed

Thanks!

Comment: I suspect that commas would appear if you would request the tokens instead of the AST

Comment: But he see it in function parameters, without additional actions.. (i add new screenshot to question)